# Avoiding header collisions when cross compiling

Tags: linux, makefile, mingw, cross-compiling

I have a linux project I want to port to windows. Under Linux I did set up my makefile to run `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` when I do call `make ARCH=win`

The problem is that some headers I need (tcl.h and friends) are located under `'/usr/include'` and if I pass that directory with the `-I` flag I will get a header collision for headers like `stdlib.h` which obviously are different for windows.

Is there a way around this besides copying the needed tcl headers into another location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sequentially order the compiler will look for header files. But no you cannot cherry pick the header file location.

A solution that you can try with this problem is using `-I/usr` and patch your project with the `sed` utility to convert the required headers like `<tcl.h>` to `<include/tcl.h>`. On top of that you can use the preprocessor to avoid patching every time your project.